# Crop a PolygonMesh in PCL

Tags: crop, mesh, cut, point-cloud-library, surface

I want to crop a PolygonMesh created with Poisson reconstruction using the Point Cloud Library (PCL). 
For point clouds this isn't a problem using the CropBox or CropHull filters.
However, these filters don't accept PolygonMesh as input type.

Is there anything that I'm missing or an easy solution to my problem?

Comment: To my knowledge, there is no ready-made function to do this. Maybe you can apply the `CropBox` filter, then access point indices that were removed by this filter, and loop through the mesh polygons, killing faces that have removed indices in them.

Comment: Why not use `CropBox` and remesh? This will work if your polygon was convex? Ideally, you'd detect which faces would get fully removed and remove those points. For faces which would get partially removed, you'd add points on the "boundary" and create new faces. I don't know what to do about the new flat "face" formed after cropping. [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5320/cutting-a-mesh-in-half)?

Comment: Thanks @taketwo. That was my idea, too so far.
What exactly do you mean with remeshing @KunalTyagi?